# docker keeps failing to build

Tags: node.js, typescript, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to build a docker container for my Node.js application with typescript. I am running this on windows 11 OS. It keeps failing with this error:

```
#8 627.1 npm ERR! path /app
#8 627.1 npm ERR! command failed
#8 627.1 npm ERR! signal SIGKILL
#8 627.1 npm ERR! command sh -c npm install
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c npm run install --only=production]: exit code: 1
```

This is my dockerfile:

```
## multi stage system
FROM node:lts-alpine

WORKDIR /app

 COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm run install 
RUN npm run build 


## this is stage two , where the app actually runs
FROM node:lts-alpine

WORKDIR /app


COPY package*.json ./ 

RUN npm run install --only=production


 COPY build .build

 RUN npm install pm2 -g

 USER node

 CMD ["pm2-runtime", "ecosystem.config.js"]

 EXPOSE 5000
```

This is the package.json file

```
{
 "name": "backend",
 "version": "1.0.0",
 "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
   "dev": "ts-node-dev --respawn src/server.ts",
    "install": "npm install",
    "build": "tsc",
    "production": "node build/src/server.js"
   },


   }
```

What I discovered to be the problem is during `RUN npm run install --only=production`. It is not working. However, if I choose to install these packages one by one like this:

```
RUN npm install axios

RUN npm install express
```

etc, the packages will install. I don't think it is nice installing them one by one with multiple run command. What could be preventing the `RUN npm run install --only=production` from installing?

Comment: Is there more to the error message than that?  It looks like you only `COPY` the npm `package.json` and `package-lock.json` files into the image, but not the application code, so I'd be suspicious of a problem related to the actual code being missing in the build line.

Comment: There is no more error logs than that. I ran a build and copied the build which has the entire code. The build compiles typecript to javascript and that folder, build, has all the codes. Is there any other thing I need to copy? Also, the docker build fails at RUN npm run install --only=production